# CSS background image with unconventional shape at the bottom

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

What is the best way to handle background images with unconventional shapes at the bottom? Here's an example:
[image]

The second background image does not look good and has a white space. Should I cut the first background image like that or should I retain the rectangle shape and do the shape on CSS?

Here's also another one:
[image]

How do I make it look like it's stacked? I'm using tailwind CSS and here's what I've done so far:

```
<div class="bg-first-section bg-cover bg-bottom"></div>
<div class="bg-second-section bg-cover bg-center"></div>

<style>
.bg-first-section {
    background-image: url('image');
}

.bg-second-section {
    background-image: url('image');
}
</style>
```

Please advice. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I think that the best way to handle that is to use a transparent png for the top image.

Comment: in addition to the duplicates, check this: https://css-generators.com/section-divider/ / https://css-generators.com/wavy-shapes/